# React: Embed tweet: Display text instead of tweet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter

I am using a WYSIWYG editor to display embeded tweets in posts, in a React app. The issue is that my editor removes all the scripts tags before saving post content in the database, and the tweet is displayed as on the picture below.

[image]

The tweet code looks like this

```
<blockquote class="twitter-tweet" data-lang="en">
  <p lang="en" dir="ltr">
    ...
  </p>
</blockquote>

<script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

I have tried to add the script in my template, just before the closing `body` tag, both with async and without async attribute, but then the tweets only render when I refresh the page.

I have try this code:

```
<div
   dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
     __html: `
        ${post.content}
        <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    `
   }}
/>
```

With this, the twitter's widget HTML load as before, the script tag is loaded at the end of the post, but it still doesn't work.

I don't know how I can get that tweet to be display normally.
Please help.

Comment: Could you try using a library like [react-load-script](https://github.com/blueberryapps/react-load-script) to load in the Twitter script? Using a string is not enough I believe, as it's not being registered correctly by the browser. It needs to happen through `document.createElement('script')`.

Comment: Not working, it is just adding the script at the end of the body. I already did that manually in my template. It is like the script most be loaded asynchronously after the Blockquote has been rendered. I think the script is just firing too earlier at that position.

Comment: I just saw somewhere that I should insert the script `<script src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>` at the end of the body, then call `twttr.widgets.load()` in `componentDidMount`. I event called it in `ComponentDidUpdate`. Still not working. Even when I call it from the browser console, still not working.

Comment: Finally got it right. the call to twttr.widgets.load() in both componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate is the solution. The problem was that, I was writing both the blockquote and the script in my editor, then while removing the script tag, on save, some extra info where added, and those info caused twttr.widgets.load() to generate error. So I just had to ignore the script tag in my editor, and everything works good now.