# Can I embed a tweet in a post on a React frontend while using headless Wordpress?

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, twitter, embed, headless

I'm building a site in React and using Wordpress as a headless CMS for the blog. Some of my posts have one or more tweets embedded in them, using Wordpress's built-in Twitter widget.

When I call the post from the Wordpress REST API, the Wordpress Twitter widget does not render. It only passes the basic content of the tweet along with the generic Twitter embed script:

`<script async="" src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>`

Is there any way I can get my React frontend to recognize the content from Wordpress as an embedded Tweet, and render it through Twitter's script so that it will look better and be more interactive?

Answer (score 3):

After more searching, I figured it out, partly thanks to this question: [React: Embed tweet: Display text instead of tweet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51991922/react-embed-tweet-display-text-instead-of-tweet)

My solution was to paste the Twitter embed script just above the closing body tag in my index.html, like:

```
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </body>
```

And then call the Twitter widget load() within useEffect (or componentDidMount / componentDidUpdate if you're using a class component):

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (window.twttr) {
      window.twttr.widgets.load();
    }
  }, []);
```

The key difference with the other StackOverflow question was the need to specify `window.`

EDIT: Adding some advice to include `if (window.twttr) {...}` in in the useEffect, because sometimes the Twitter script doesn't load (or possibly just hasn't finished loading *yet*), and that breaks the whole page for no reason.

Comment: It works with Next.js too.